# Mobile-friendly audio player for Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, html5-audio

I'm currently building a Rails app, where a user can upload an mp3 and listen to it. I'm using paperclip for the data upload, but I'm not sure how I'd arrange the playback of the soundfile, so that it can be used on a mobile phone as well (so no flash).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two main cross-browser media playback frameworks are [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) and [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).

Both will handle playback of your audio, regardless of device. Both will play the audio using either HTML5 or Flash according to

- which solution is available
- which solution you specified as higher priority (e.g. use HTML if available, Flash if not)

Comment: looks great, especially since they are open-source. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players) and I'm very happy about it. There is a HTML 5 mode that runs on newer mobile devices like the iPhone.